# Is it possible to call the destructor without knowing the type?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is it possible to call the destructor of an object without knowing the class type without using `delete`? I am asking because I am working on an allocator (for fun/ practice) and I am using `malloc`/ placement `new` to constructor the object but then when I go to destruct the object, I was curious if there was a way to do so without knowing the type. If it is not possible, why not? Is it the only way to do is the way I show in my sample code (that is commented out)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <new>

void* SomeAllocationFunction(size_t size) {
    return malloc(size);
}

class SomeClass{
public:
    SomeClass() {
        printf("Constructed\n");
    }

    ~SomeClass() {
        printf("Destructed\n");
    }
};

int main(void){
    void* mem = SomeAllocationFunction(sizeof(SomeClass));
    SomeClass* t = new(mem)SomeClass;

    free(t);
    //t->~SomeClass(); // This will call the destructor, is it possible to do this without knowing the class?

    return 0;
}
```

(I know I can just call delete, but please ignore that for the moment.)

Comment: The only way to call a class-specific function without knowing the class at compile-time is if there is some class-specific information built into every instance, which can be used to perform a lookup at run-time (similar to the vtbl concept).  That's generally not the case.

Comment: When you do end up calling `t->~SomeClass()`, you'll definitely want to do that *before* `free(t)`.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: That was just commented out code, I did not mean to confuse with the order.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: That would be a lot of overhead, wouldn't it?

Comment: @mmurphy: Well, no more than is used to implement polymorphism.

Comment: Every time I've tried something like this, (and I have - in other languages like Delphi, you can free any object without any 'external' class info so I've tried this in C++), it has resulted in, err...  'less than optimal forward progress'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible without knowing the type (or knowing one of the object's base types that has a virtual destructor).

Typically speaking, custom allocators neither construct nor destruct the object, though some make a templated wrapper around the allocator that performs a placement new or a direct destructor call.

(Technically, you could associate with every allocation a function pointer that ends up calling the type's destructor. But that's fairly sketchy, and I wouldn't recommend it.)

Comment: I suppose then the wrapper would need to know the type for the direct destructor call? (Like a macro)

Comment: Yep; it'd be templated on the type of the object being destroyed. Wouldn't have to look any different than the `free()` call, though, because the type could be inferred.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't call the destructor without knowing the class, because the compiler doesn't know which destructor to call. You could either:

- Make all objects inherit from some base object that has a virtual destructor, and use that base object pointer instead of a void pointer
- Make use of templates
- Have the allocator itself not manage the calling of constructors/destructors

Answer (score 2):

It is no more possible to call the destructor on an untyped piece of memory than it is to call a constructor (ie: placement new) without a type. Both the constructor and the destructor are part of the object, and the compiler needs a type to know what to call.

Answer (score 0):

As of C++17 this has become possible with `std::destroy_at`. See [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at).